# Supporting multiple screens in android by default

Tags: android, android-screen-support

**I am looking at supporting multiple screens in android**

*Assume i have used below structure in the project*

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size 
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size
```

---

1. So as above i am providing three similar layouts where in case of
   `normal screen`, `large screen`, `extra-large screen`so that
   appropriate xml's are taken.
2. Now i delete the  `res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml` from my project
   structure

---

**Questions::**

- If now i run my application in `extra-large screen` which
  `my_layout.xml` will be taken from my project structure is it `normal
  screen size` or `large screen size` because `extra-large screen` is
  deleted.
- Reason why this happens

Comment: `layout-large`, because it's the closest.

Answer (score 0):

If now i run my application in extra-large screen which my_layout.xml will be taken from my project structure?

```
        The layout in res/layout-large/my_layout.xml will be taken to run your application.

    Reason why this happens?

       layout-large is selected to run your application because it is the layout that has the size closer to the layout-xlarge.
```